# Как сделать конструктор текстовой части страницы?

Tags: html

В последнее время почти на всех сайтах, включая этот замечаю функцию, позволяющую форматировать текст при помощи его окантовки в кавычки, звёздочки итд. Вот пример с этого сайта:

````
```код``` **полужирный** *курсив* >цитата
````

Как реализовать такой удобный текстовый редактор страницы?

**Просьба поправить вопрос, если знаете, как донести суть понятнее*

Comment: Это называется [markdown](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=markdown)

Comment: @Simon, у markdown намного больше возможностей чем просто несколько видов выделений

Comment: именно со спец.символами, обычными, как сказали выше - murkDown, но есть и иные варианты: 1 murkUp - тупо банальные теги(древние блоги как раз голый html принимают). 2 BBcode(грубо говоря это те же теги, только с квадратными скобками). 3 как раз **murkDown** (тут только популярные спец символы в качестве тегов). 4 текстовые процессоры(*.doc, *.rtf и прочие офисные форматы... у них в качестве тегов используются наоборот непечатаемые спец-символы, из за чего переключать режимы в них, тот еще "кайф").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Эта разметка называется MarkDown . Возьми готовый редактор, например, showdown.

Или вам целый сайт целиком? Тогда можно попробовать что-то из этого списка https://github.com/myles/awesome-static-generators

Comment: Спасибо, это оказалось то, что нужно